# Google colab not opening suddenly

Tags: google-colaboratory

[image]

Hi, I am trying to load the colab. It was working perfectly suddenly it stopped loading.

I tried to clear cookies, reinstalled chrome and opened it in incognito mode. But nothing works.

Can anyone suggest what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted the colab folder from drive. On uploading it again, it worked. I don't know how this happened but I am sharing this as someone might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. Discussion is at:
https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2251

I'd recommend following up there to help with diagnosis.